# How do I find out a topics data type?

Tags: ros, realsense-camera, realsense

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using rosbridge to get camera data from a ros to a non-ros device

I can see the topic `/camera/depth/points` but I'm not sure what "type" it is. For now I'm using `std_msgs/String` but I'm not sure if that's it. How can I find out for sure what the "type" is?

realsense ros source:
https://github.com/intel-ros/realsense

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246324/how-do-i-find-out-a-topics-data-type?/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rostopic info /camera/depth/points`?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-10-24**:
You've got to be kidding me..

Regardless, thanks.

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2016-10-25**:
Also, it helps to use [rqt](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt) for stuff like this so you don't have to memorize command line stuff. The Topic Monitor plugin shows all the topics, their types, and you can monitor their values.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-25**:\

> [..] so you don't have to memorize command line stuff.

I guess it's a matter of opinion, but personally I do prefer to "memorize command line stuff", as I don't need to start UIs for something as simple as this. Works across SSH sessions as well, and platforms without X.